Composer file_put_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
Im trying to install breeze on my Lara Project with composer require laravel/breeze --dev
but it show up
I already browsing in internet and doing all solution that i found, i grant permission on File Explorer, Administrator CMD, reinstall the composer, but still
I hope you guys can help me
I already browsing in internet and doing all solution that i found, i grant permission on File Explorer, Administrator CMD, reinstall the composer, made new role/user in security,changig ownership of the bin and the parents, reinstalling composer in developer mode and no-dev mode but still wont work, there is something i want to do but i dont know how, maybe can we change the directory path, so when im run the command its not direct to C:\Program Data\ComposerSetup\bin again ?
I hope you guys can help me

which version of leravel you are using?

ummm Laravel Framework 11.9.2, yeah

"it show up" - what does that mean? If you refer to the error message from the title: where do you run composer require?

runin my composer require in my lara project? with administrator role

Why do you use admin permissions for this?

because i see in the folder permission admin is has full control, so i tried, but i get the same error

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. It's not a surprise that an admin user has full control over most of the parts on your computer, but usually, you should not use such admin users to run Composer (because you should usually never user your admin account, unless you really need it)

Started with Laravel a week ago and I encountered the same problem, my solution was to manually change the system variable for composer (in the Environment Variables).
After the installation of composer, it was automatically set to "C:\Program Data\ComposerSetup\bin".
I changed this to my installation folder of composer ("C:\xampp\composer\bin").
This solved this problem for me.
(okay, run into other problems when trying to install, but that's not for this thread).

(working with the terminal inside VS Code @ win10, laravel11, breeze 2.1.0, php 8.2.12, npm 10.8.1)

i had the same problem.
Composer version 2.7.7
PHP version 8.2.12
Go to Environmental variables >> look for Composer in System variables and delete the Composer reaching to your bin folder of composer. Do not delete the COMPOSER_HOME.
Afterwards restart your code environment and you should be good to go.
