file_put_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
I'm trying to install Laravel and tried to compose another like swagger and jwt, the thing is that i can't install it and got a error
file_put_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

so each time i tried this
composer require tymon/jwt-auth

composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger

I got an error.
Here is what i install.
Composer version 2.7.7 2024-06-10 22:11:12
PHP version 8.2.12 (C:\xampp\php\php.exe)
Laravel Installer 5.8.2
and I'm using Windows 11


C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin tried to set all the security in Full Control

I got stuck in here. How to solve this?
Disclaimer: I'm new in laravel.

similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78581580/composer-file-put-contentsc-programdata-composersetup-bin-failed-to-open-str

install composer again

Installing Laravel should usually not involve any files in C:\ProgramData - how do you run Composer? Also, are you sure that your problem is related to Laravel or Swagger itself?

bin is usually a name for directories with binary (executable) files. Are you sure, that C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin is not a directory?

@NicoHaase i usually used visual studio code and do a composer using powershell. the laravel is okay but when i tried to install the jwt and the swagger the error goes like permission denied.

@Subha i did i install it like 3x

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. From which folder do you run composer require? And do you use elevated permissions (like an admin console)?

@NicoHaase Here is what i did i create a folder in the desktop which is i generate a laravel there. there i use the composer require

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

I answered a somewhat similar problem a few weeks ago, maybe it can help you a bit further, my solution to that problem was to manually change the system variable for composer (in the Environment Variables).
After the installation of composer, it was automatically set to "C:\Program Data\ComposerSetup\bin".

I changed this to my installation folder of composer ("C:\xampp\composer\bin"). 
(working with the terminal inside VS Code @ win10, laravel11, breeze 2.1.0, php 8.2.12, npm 10.8.1)
